# Texmaker: Check Spelling - Always Ignore

Tags: texmaker, mac, spelling

For the first time I have used the *Edit > Check Spelling* feature on Texmaker to extensively check a large document. During the process, I have clicked the *Always ignore* button for some words. Now, those words are as if in the dictionary and are not properly checked for spelling. Here is an example:

[image: Texmaker spell check.]

The **rel** and **res** words are not correct and should be red underlined. Texmaker must have added those words to some file without my knowledge--I though the always ignore option was for that session only. I did this on a previous version of Texmaker on Mac OS Snow Leopard. I've reinstalled to the most recent version (4.0.2) and the problem persists.

I guess that the underlying TeX engine has nothing to do with this.

Anything to do with Hunspell?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hi and a big [welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I'm not using Texmaker but in TexStudio (on Windows) when a word is "always ignored", it's automatically added to a particular file, named `en_GB.ign` (or whatever, according to your language). Check if this file is empty -- it should be in the `\dictionaries` folder in the Texmaker istallation root.

Comment: Thanks. Texmaker does not have that folder on Mac OS nor `find / -name "en_US.ign"` (I was using the American dictionary) finds the file through the terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "always ignored words" are stored in the Texmaker configuration file. "Options" -> "Settings file" -> "reset settings".

And, if you want to ignore a word for only one document, just use the "ignore" button and not the "always ignore" one.

Comment: Worked! Thanks for the heads up. Did not know about that configuration file. It sure eases copying Texmaker settings from one computer to another.

Answer (score 0):

Just have the same issue and study a bit on this interesting topic.  I use texmaker version 5.0.4 Windows X64.

If the software was installed, find the place below:

```
C:\Users\"username"\AppData\Roaming\xm1\texmaker.ini
```

If the software was portable version, find the **texmaker.ini** file in program folder.

On the line started with "Spell\Words", the ignored lists exist there.