# Errors of spellingchecker hunspell in TeXmaker

Tags: texmaker, spelling

I installed the update Ubuntu 18.04. Afterwards the spell checker in TeXmaker makes some errors. It is related to interpret the rules in *.aff. Does someone recognize this?

Programs: 
TeXmaker 5.0.2;
Hunspell 1.6.2-1;
nl_NL.aff and nl_NL.dic version 2.10G version date 2011-09-23

The following words are marked as spelled incorrectly:
zijn, bekijken, wordt, verschillende, bijvoorbeeld

Comment: you could look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121345/texmaker-check-spelling-always-ignore?rq=1 Unfortunately as your issue appears to not be tex specific unless you can confirm there is a difference in correct/wrong without/within Texmaker (in which case that would need to be the support route) and has a platform specific bug report route I suggest you try https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hunspell