# How can I return to the default spell checking dictionary?

Tags: texmaker

I clicked "always ignore" for some misspelled words, and now I need to get back the original dictionary and continue to check those misspelled words. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you checked https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121345/texmaker-check-spelling-always-ignore The "always ignored words" are stored in the Texmaker configuration file. "Options" -> "Settings file" -> "reset settings".

Comment: Yes, this worked, thanks!